# oil in ashtray?

Tags: oil, oil-leak

I reached into ashtray where I keep the key and fingers came out dripping oil...The ashtray was FULL of used oil and there was a puddle of the same on drivers floor.
Coolant reservoir seems to only have coolant in it, and in radiator while there IS rust colored fluid it does not seem oily or bubbling as a head gasket fail might show.
Could this still be signs of a head gasket failure?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I don't know of a single vehicle I'm aware of which would have oil routed into the occupant cabin (at least that way from the factory). Are you *sure* it's actually engine oil? Is the oil level low in the engine? Really, I think I'd do the feel/see/taste test on whatever it is, because I'd lay money on it *not* being engine oil (unless someone put it there to get at you for some reason).

Comment: If it has a manual oil pressure gauge, the line feeding it could be leaking....